# Why would NodeJS give a "Unexpected identifier" error when calling a require'd function?

Tags: node.js, webpack

I just upgraded a big frontend project to build with Webpack 5, which required updating a bunch of loader plugins.  One of these is the `string-replace-plugin`.  It's a simple plugin that is implemented with 3 short source files.  When initially installed, each of these files is created with a timestamp of "26 October 1985, 10:15:00 PM", per [npm convention](https://npm.community/t/tarball-content-timestamps-locked-to-1985/149/3).  I checked and a bunch of other loaders are installed with a similar structure.

My normal builds work fine like this, but I get an error when running `karma` using the `karma-webpack` plugin.  It throws a `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` on [this line](https://github.com/Va1/string-replace-loader/blob/master/lib/processChunk.js#L7), pointing to the call to the require'd function `getOptionsArray`.  Through trial and error, I discovered that **simply `touch`-ing `getOptionsArray.js`** causes the error to go away.

I don't have a simple reproduction for this issue -- it only happens when my particular Webpack config is invoked through `karma-webpack`, so it would have to be pretty complex.  Instead, I'm trying to understand what could cause behavior like this.  `touch`-ing the calling code (`processChunk.js`) does not fix it.  It's not failing at the `require("./getOptionsArray")` line, but rather when the returned function is actually called.  I added a `console.log(typeof getOptionsArray)` just before the line that errors out, and it writes `getOptionsArray`, so it's definitely require'd correctly / exists / is defined, just before the SyntaxError is thrown.

In the short term, I could have my test runner `touch` the file so that the tests pass, but that feels completely crazy.  I'd really like to track down exactly how this is failing and get it fixed, but I'm at the limit of my understanding of `karma` / `webpack` / `node` interactions here, and don't know how to keep digging.

Comment: what version of string-replace-plugin are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I should have included this.  Webpack 5.10.1, string-replace-loader 3.0.1, karma 5.2.3, karma-webpack 5.0.0-alpha.5

Comment: there was an issue with webpack but it seems resolved since 3.0.0 https://github.com/Va1/string-replace-loader/issues/59 Take a look if it could be related to your problem